# Indicate whether a post is a question or an answer in the mod tools

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools

It is not possible to distinguish between quesitons and answers that are flagged for action in mod tools.  It would be nice to be able to know in some cases.

A simple hint would be to format the user's name as it would be within a question:

[image: an example of the format]

and leave answers formatted the way they currently are:

[image: standard example]

Comment: On a similar basis, I've have thought it would be nice to remove the mark as spam/offensive links if you've already voted, but I fully realise that the moderator tools are a lower priority for such UI enhancements. (Then again, perhaps I should bugger off and create my own "question".) :-)

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't the presence of the word "asked" versus "answered" illustrate this? It could be seen as subtle, but it is there in the dashboard view.

---

This has been improved further, and in fact is rendered similar to what you requested. The question will be highlighted just like their user card is on the question page itself. It is just a highlight, it does not retain the other elements such as the Accept Rate.

I don't know about self-answers, but keep in mind that [self-answers are explicitly indicated further](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82770/additional-information-for-moderator-flags), which will hopefully prevent confusing them as being the question.

Comment: Apparently not, since I completely didn't catch that, lol.  Would still like to see the additional information, such as accept rate (which I often check before dealing with "please raise your accept rate" comments)