# Additional information for moderator flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

Here's an example of what moderators currently see when an answer is flagged for attention.

[image: Flag Information]

There are two small pieces of additional information that would speed up the processing of this kind of flag.

1. The date the question was posted. This could go right under the question title.  I'd like to see the question date so I can see the lag between the question and the flagged answer.  New answers on new questions seem a little more urgent to me than new answers on old questions, since the former is likely to be more active.
2. The fact that the person who asked the question also posted this answer.  This could be accomplished with the same highlighting that's currently used in answers and comments when the OP responds.

   If a post is flagged as "not an answer" I typically look at the date to see if it's fresh or not.  If it's a really old post I usually just delete it from the flag page (using the handy "delete post" link).  If it's new, I'll often go to the post and leave a comment saying that they should have posted a new question.  This takes a little more time, but it's friendlier to new users.

   If the "answer" was a follow-up question from the OP, I'd know that I probably need to go in and edit it into the original question.  I at least need to go take a look.  If it's a follow-up from someone else, I'd be more confident that I can safely delete it from the flag page without losing any information.

Comment: It'd be nice to have some sort of vote for other moderators to see. For example, I'd vote that I "agree" with the flag, but I'm unsure if I should act and I'd like to know the opinion of my fellow mods (and I cannot enter chat all the time to ask them) before acting on it, or dismissing it.

Comment: @Juan: I usually just go in an look at post so the other mods can see that I've visited it and taken no action.  That's not as strong as "I agree" but it does at least say "I don't know about this one."  If I want to send a stronger message about it I can always re-flag it.

Comment: I don't think looking at it is a stand. I usually reach the point of agreeing or not with the flag after reading the actual post; and regarding re-flagging, we don't like to do that

Comment: I assume the [status-completed] is for the second point, not the first one?

Comment: @Grace: I'm seeing the timestamp that the question was asked underneath the answerer's gravatar on SO flags.

Comment: Might be SO or Trilogy specific, I guess. Gaming just has the join date. Trilogy is the place where it is most important, though.

Comment: @Grace: That's weird, we have the same revision number.  Edit: Now that I look a little closer, I see that only *most* of the answer flags also have the question's posted date.  Removing [status-completed].

Comment: I did some research and posted it below. Since the first point is addressed opposite to what you're wanting, you don't need to accept it or mark it status-completed yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These have both been (to some degree) implemented.

The second point, `the person who asked the question also posted this answer`, is fully implemented. Any such item will be appropriately marked.

The first point, `the date the question was posted`, is conditionally applied. It only seems to apply when there is a significant difference between the Ask date and the Answer date. In other words, it's for new answers to old questions - somewhat the opposite of what you desire, it seems.

Comment: Thanks for investigating.  It does seem to be opposite of what I asked for, but I can still use the (absence of) information to do what I need to do.